# Fetch only True values of particular keys from table using python without pandas?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to take values from a DB table where It has keys as enabled and values as true, false and empty, I want to take only True values from enabled keys and other keys and rows related to it.

Table

```
    id    name    enabled dept
     1    abd     TRUE    cs
     2    cdew    FALSE   ds
     3    sda             sd
     4    asd     TRUE    as
```

I want only enabled = true values from table. how can I do it? without help of pandas? I want like

```
    id    name    enabled dept
     1    abd     TRUE    cs
     4    asd     TRUE    as
```

Comment: Hi, @Mia ! Which database do you use?  In case of SQL databases like MySQL or PostgreSQL it would be better to use SQL for filtering data, not Python.

Comment: from aws dynamodb

Comment: Are you using the Python API? https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.query

`KeyConditionExpression=Key('enabled').eq(True)`

Comment: no im using table scan with ProjectionExpression and ExpressionAttributeNames

Comment: Better create a GSI on the enabled column and use the query operation instead of scan. Scan operation is costly as your data will increase

Comment: @Paul Bauriegel, What should i use in place of Key ?

Answer (score 1):

Best thing to do is create a Sparse Index which only had the True values.

To do this, only set `enabled` for True values and if False just omit it as DynamoDB is schemaless.

Now create a GSI with the partition or sort key as `enabled`, now the GSI will only contain the items you want. To fetch them simply `Scan` the GSI.
GSI:

```
id(pk)  enabled(sk) name   dept
 1       TRUE       abd     cs
 4       TRUE       asd     as
```

Comment: pls send any docs related to the exact GSI

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-general-sparse-indexes.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using below code. thanks all for your help

```
resp= key.get('enabled',None)
if resp:
```